# When I attempt to remove g++ why does apt-get attempt to install it?

Tags: 12.04, apt, g++

*Note: Originally I had a long background explanation leading up to why I was trying to perform `apt-get remove g++`. I have deleted that as irrelevant after trying this in a clean install of 11.10 (32-bit) and then, after upgrading, in 12.04.*

*It appears to be a problem only 12.04. Time to change focus and see if this is a reported bug.*

---

*I did not find anything that looked related so I reported this as [Bug #982716](http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt/+bug/982716).*

---

While attempting to get rid of a problem compiling Octave I removed all the packages needed to compile Octave so I could then re-install them. While doing this I ran into an unexpected response from `apt-get` in 12.04.

When I attempt to remove the `g++` package, apt-get instead attempts to install `g++-4.6`. I expected to get the message `Package g++ is not installed, so not removed`. Why didn't I?

```
me@BlueUbuntu64:~$ sudo apt-get -V --dry-run remove g++
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
   g++-4.6 (4.6.3-1ubuntu4)
   libstdc++6-4.6-dev (4.6.3-1ubuntu4)
Suggested packages:
   g++-multilib (4.6.3-1ubuntu5)
   g++-4.6-multilib (4.6.3-1ubuntu4)
   gcc-4.6-doc (4.6.3-1ubuntu4)
   libstdc++6-4.6-dbg (4.6.3-1ubuntu4)
   libstdc++6-4.6-doc (4.6.3-1ubuntu4)
The following NEW packages will be installed:
   g++ (4.6.3-1ubuntu5)
   g++-4.6 (4.6.3-1ubuntu4)
   libstdc++6-4.6-dev (4.6.3-1ubuntu4)
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Inst libstdc++6-4.6-dev (4.6.3-1ubuntu4 Ubuntu:12.04/precise [amd64]) []
Inst g++-4.6 (4.6.3-1ubuntu4 Ubuntu:12.04/precise [amd64])
Inst g++ (4:4.6.3-1ubuntu5 Ubuntu:12.04/precise [amd64])
Conf libstdc++6-4.6-dev (4.6.3-1ubuntu4 Ubuntu:12.04/precise [amd64])
Conf g++-4.6 (4.6.3-1ubuntu4 Ubuntu:12.04/precise [amd64])
Conf g++ (4:4.6.3-1ubuntu5 Ubuntu:12.04/precise [amd64])
```

---

#### Update

Result of specifying `--no-install-recommends` option to `apt-get`. Surprisingly (to me) seems to fail the same way. Will also (eventually) update the bug report. (Why not?)

```
me@Vbubux86-11:~$ sudo apt-get -V --dry-run --no-install-recommends remove g++
[sudo] password for me: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
   g++-4.6 (4.6.3-1ubuntu4)
   libstdc++6-4.6-dev (4.6.3-1ubuntu4)
Suggested packages:
   g++-multilib (4.6.3-1ubuntu5)
   g++-4.6-multilib (4.6.3-1ubuntu4)
   gcc-4.6-doc (4.6.3-1ubuntu4)
   libstdc++6-4.6-dbg (4.6.3-1ubuntu4)
   libstdc++6-4.6-doc (4.6.3-1ubuntu4)
The following NEW packages will be installed:
   g++ (4.6.3-1ubuntu5)
   g++-4.6 (4.6.3-1ubuntu4)
   libstdc++6-4.6-dev (4.6.3-1ubuntu4)
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Inst libstdc++6-4.6-dev (4.6.3-1ubuntu4 Ubuntu:12.04/precise [i386]) []
Inst g++-4.6 (4.6.3-1ubuntu4 Ubuntu:12.04/precise [i386])
Inst g++ (4:4.6.3-1ubuntu5 Ubuntu:12.04/precise [i386])
Conf libstdc++6-4.6-dev (4.6.3-1ubuntu4 Ubuntu:12.04/precise [i386])
Conf g++-4.6 (4.6.3-1ubuntu4 Ubuntu:12.04/precise [i386])
Conf g++ (4:4.6.3-1ubuntu5 Ubuntu:12.04/precise [i386])
me@Vbubux86-11:~$ apt-cache policy g++
g++:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 4:4.6.3-1ubuntu5
  Version table:
     4:4.6.3-1ubuntu5 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main i386 Packages
```

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that it might be part of one of those standard desktop program lists. Every desktop has, for example, a simple text editor. Some use gedit, but there are many replacements. Maybe g++ is one of those, and so apt is selecting another package that provides that feature and it just happens to be a different version of g++

Comment: Given that this was know confirmed as a bug, this question is now considered as relevant only to **as specific moment in time** and hence has been closed as too-localised.  Thanks.

Comment: @irrationalJohn Bug tag is a meta tag. It has no use on this site.

Comment: @jrg Oh. So the [tag:bug] should be deleted from this site then, no? Or are you saying that there is one common set of tags which is shared by both the main and the meta sites of Ask Ubuntu?

Comment: @irrationalJohn It is a 'meta' tag in that it has no useful meaning - if it really is a bug, then it shouldn't be posted here to begin with! So the tag is more or less useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From an update to [Bug #982716](http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt/+bug/982716):

```
This bug was fixed in the package apt - 0.8.16~exp12ubuntu10
```

(I never did get around to attaching the result of also including `--no-install-recommends`. Oh, well.)

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this:

```
sudo apt-get -V --dry-run --no-install-recommends remove g++
```